# How to assign 2 foreign keys to one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the tables `roles` and `users`. The `id` from `roles` is the foreign key of the column `role` in the table `users`.
There are 2 roles: `support` and manager. How can I specify, that the user `peter` is assigned both of the 2 roles?

roles

```
| id | role    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | support |
| 2  | manager |
```

users

```
| id | user     | pass  | role (FK) |
|----|----------|-------|-----------|
| 1  | peter    | hash1 | 1,2       | <-- 2 foreign keys
| 2  | jennifer | hash2 | 2         |
```

Comment: you can always go this route.. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic Many to Many Relationship. One user can have many roles and one role can be assigned to many users.
You should probably need to create a new UserRole table with info like this:

```
id userId roleId
1    1      1
2    1      2
3    2      2
4 ...
```

If you don't want surrogate keys, remove id and make userId+roleId Primary Key:

```
userId roleId
  1      1
  1      2
  2      2
```

Comment: First column (`id`) is redundant. Additionally `userId + roleId` should be `PK`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev `id` is just a surrogate key. Some people like'em some don't. In my sample `id` would be `PK` and `userId+roleId UK`.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a third table - user_roles - with columns role_id and user_id